# Why is my Bootstrap Carousel not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular7

I am making a MEAN stack application using angular 7. I use a *Bootstrap Carousel* but it's not working.

```css
#slider .item {
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--all above is necessary for bootstrap to function in this snippet-->


<div class="carousel slide" id="slider" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="../../assets/public/RoadTipsMain.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
        <p>Travel! Enjoy!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide2">
      <img src="../../assets/public/5.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
        <p>Travel! Enjoy!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide3">
      <img src="../../assets/public/cardrive.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
        <p>Travel! Enjoy!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slider" data-slide="prev" role="button"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slider" data-slide="next" role="button"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
</div>
```

Is there any mistake I am doing with the code? I think `#slider` is not working in angular 7.

Comment: have you tried `carousel-item` instead of `item` class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load Carousel - Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129715/cant-load-carousel-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129715/cant-load-carousel-bootstrap-4/55130082#55130082) (marked as duplicate but nothing happened):

> You have to give all *items* (pictures) of the carousel the class
>   `carousel-item` but you only gave them the class `item`. Same with the
>   *Previous* and *Next* buttons. The classes should be `carousel-control-prev` and `carousel-control-next` but you only gave
>   them the class `carousel-control`.
>
> The rest seems to be working just fine! When handling Bootstrap you
>   always have to look out for the classes since they have to be exactly
>   right for it to work at all. (You could also probably remove the
>   `popper.js`-script at the bottom since it is not used at all.)
>
> **So basically just change all `<div class="item">` to `<div class="carousel-item">` and add `-next` and `-prev` to the control
>   classes as I did here:**

```css
#slider .carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.carousel-item>img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--all above is necessary for bootstrap to function in this snippet-->



<div class="carousel slide" id="slider" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600/">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
        <p>Travel! Enjoy!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item" id="slide2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600/">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
        <p>Travel! Enjoy!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item" id="slide3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600/">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
        <p>Travel! Enjoy!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If I try to run this code in my application exactly as it is, using the same scripts carousel is not created. You can check the codepen that I've created for Bootstrap 4.1: https://codepen.io/zlristovski/pen/bGpyEWK

Comment: @Dragon Your CodePen works for me. Just the images aren't loaded because they are referenced incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem like that.
You must be careful to read again Getting Started carousel focused on Dependency. 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Don't forget to add BootstrapCDN (content delivery network)  in your HTML file:
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

this is my BootstrapCDN in my workspace:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).